# Python ZeroMQ module import error

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I installed ZeroMQ by adding the official ZeroMQ repo to my sources, then installed it via`apt-get install libzmq3-dev`, then installed the module using `apt-get install python-zmq`.

When I open up a python interpreter and type in `import zmq`, I get the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "zmq.py", line 2, in <module>
    context = zmq.Context()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Context'
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible you've got a file in your project called `zmq.py` and you're accidentally importing that?

You should always use absolute_import with Python 2.x (from [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports)) to avoid these types of issues.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably also need to run

```
apt-get install libzmq3
```

to get the actual compiled library installed. `-dev` packages are generally just source code/headers, and don't actually provide the functionality of the library itself. If you do this, you should be all set.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as OP on Ubuntu 14.04.2 and your solution didn't help. Any other ideas?

Comment: Not true. `libzmq3-dev` depends on `libzmq3`. You can check for yourself: `apt-cache show libzmq3-dev | grep Depends`.